# Installing CentOS 6.4 on Xen 6.0: Install hangs on "Switching to clocksource hyperv_clocksource"

Tags: centos6, xenserver

When I tried to install CentOS 6.4 on a Citrix XenServer 6.0, after I hit install, the installation hangs at "Switching to clocksource hyperv_clocksource"

I have installed CentOS 6.0 without this issue on the same server.

Any suggestions is much appreciated, and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

To get around this issue, you will need to set the clocksource to hpet. To do this, let grub load the screen, then hit the tab key. Add this to the end of the command: `clocksource=hpet`

I tried using `clocksource=acpi_pm` and `clocksource=xen` , however both fail. Only using hpet was I able to complete the install.

Comment: Also found that 'clocksource=jiffy' will work as well

Comment: Awasome it's works, Thanks I am able to install it using clocksource=hpet

Comment: Dude thanks, I've been having this problem for days...

Answer (score 1):

I have actually noticed this problem as well with xenserver 6.2

I ended up having to put clocksource=jiffies clocksource_failover=hpet

Comment: I was having the same problem as OP, and by setting clocksource=jiffies the installation could proceed. Many thanks for you reply!